# SQL Update on a network database in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to have a local access program that does not contain the table of data. The real database is on a SharePoint and I have the full network path to it. I can do a SQL SELECT statement and access it no problem

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] IN '\\Network\\Path\\File.accdb';
```

But when I try to do an update statement with the same syntax, I get an error, "Too few arguments, expected 3."

```
UPDATE [Table] IN '\\Network\Path\\File.accdb' SET [Column 1] = 'New Value', [Column 2] = 'Value', [Column 3] = 'Another value' WHERE [ID] = 4;
```

Comment: How many columns do you have in the table?

Comment: There are 12 columns. When I do an update I'm not updating every column.

Comment: Figured it out. Apparently I had changed one of my column names in the database but forgot to update it in the front-end program itself. The above command does work properly

Comment: Happy that you find solution